# jquery: can't get input value

Tags: jquery, variables, null

I'm trying send my value to ajax but it seems empty parameter.
Then I try like:

```
<input type="text" id="IDtag"/>
<button id="check"></button>

$('#check').click(function(){
    var IDnum = $("#IDtag").val();
    alert (IDnum);
});
```

alert is null even I already fill some value into `IDtag`.

---

UPDATE
[image: after fill input]

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Zfs7V/

Comment: @Kabie: it must be work, but no error in my page (see my comment to Gautam answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5cVZH/)**

use document.ready..

```
$(function(){
    $('#check').click(function(){
       var IDnum = $("#IDtag").val();
       alert (IDnum);
   });
});
```

Comment: the alert is appear, but null.

Comment: you have to enter value in textbox

Comment: type $("#IDtag").val() in console window and execute .check value is coming or not

Comment: r u checked in console window

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35971/discussion-between-nunu-and-prabu-parthipan)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.on()` and put the script on `DOM ready` like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#check').on('click',function(){
        var IDnum = $("#IDtag").val();
        alert (IDnum);
    });
});
```

And also put the button like

```
<input type="button" id="check" value="check">
```

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rShWf/1/)

Comment: my chrome shows pause in debugger `$('#check').on('click',function(){`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $('#check').live('click',function(){        
        alert($("#IDtag").val());
    });
});
```